# Custom Stop Button HTML5 Video

Tags: html, video, controls, custom-controls, html5-video

So im trying to make a little video with custom controls, it is the first time, so i have no idea what im doing. but i have godt the play pause putton to work, but how do i make a stop button?

My code:

Video player:

```
<div class="videobox">
    <video id="video" width="100%" height="100%">
      <source src="testvideo.m4v" type="video/mp4">
      <p>
        Your browser doesn't support HTML5 video.
      </p>
    </video>
</div>
```

And my controls

```
<div class="buttonrow">
    <input type="range" id="seek-bar" value="0">
    <button type="button" id="play-pause" class="play">Play</button>
    <button type="button" id="mute">Mute</button>
    <input type="range" id="volume-bar" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" value="1">
    <button type="button" id="full-screen">Full-Screen</button>
</div>
```

Hope someone can help me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### HTML

```
<input type="button" value="play" id="playBtn" />
<input type="button" value="pause" id="pauseBtn" />
<input type="button" value="stop" id="stopBtn" />
```

#### jQuery

```js
var source = "http://www.giorgiosardo.com/HTML5/audio/audio/sample.mp3"
var audio = document.createElement("audio"); audio.src = source;

$("#playBtn").click(function () {
    audio.play();
});

$("#pauseBtn").click(function () {
    audio.pause();
});

$("#stopBtn").click(function () {
    audio.pause();
    audio.currentTime = 0;
});
```

Hope this helps. [Source](http://yassershaikh.com/play-pause-and-stop-an-audio-in-html-5-by-example/)

Comment: I can see that your example is for audio, is it the same for video? :)

Comment: you can integrate the same logic for video. - @user2354493

Comment: I suggest you to make permutations from the source to see weather it works for you or not. - @Legarndary

Comment: my solution was like this:

 stopButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  video.pause(); 
  video.currentTime = 0;
  playButton.innerHTML = "Play";
});